# DevExpress error is missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, devexpress

I am working with mvc and DevExpress trying to force a download of a report that I already have created

I have the following error:

> The type or name of the 'Reports' namespace does not exist in the 'BLL.Reportes' namespace (missing any assembly reference?)

My code C#

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {

        var report = new BLL.Reportes.SolicitudReporte(); <--- error
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        report.ExportToPdf(stream);
        var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName = "ReportTest.pdf",
            Inline = false,
        };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return File(stream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");
    }
```

If I am using my reference to my project called "BLL"....

[image]
[image]

Comment: I had same problem sometimes. You can try following: 1. Clean solution, then build. 2. Restart the solution.  3. Remove the .suo file in your .vs directory. For this you have to show hidden folders and files. Maybe one of this works for you.

Comment: i just tried all the points but nothing so far

Comment: Try to remove the reference. Then go to the class and visual studio should show this error again. But it should help you find it. Add it with visual studio. Maybe this works

Comment: Ready, I have now solved the problem that I have when you download the pdf file that is blank

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the reference and add it again with the visual studio function:
[image]

Comment: Ready, I have now solved the problem that I have when you download the pdf file that is blank